# Add to cell in a Pandas dataframe from a dictionary in another cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
datadict = {"StationID":[102,103,11],"Bikes_Available":[10,3,2], "Suggested_Movements":[{11:3,103:5}, {11:3}, {103:1}]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datadict)

StationID Bikes_Available   Suggested_Movements
102       10                {11: 3, 103: 5}
103        3                {11: 3}
11         2                {103: 1}
```

The last column is a dictionary. The keys represent a StationID that bikes should be moved to, and the values are the number of bikes that should be moved. I want to create a new column that shows how many bikes should be added to each StationID. I need to look up each dictionary of Suggested_Movements and sum all the bikes that are being moved to each station.
The output would look like this:

```
StationID Bikes_Available   Suggested_Movements To_Add
102       10                {11: 3, 103: 5}      0
103        3                {11: 2}              6
11         2                {103: 1}             5
```

Station 102 gets 0 bikes added. Station 103 gets 6 added, 5 from station 102 and 1 from station 11. Station 11 gets 5 added, 3 from 102 and 2 from 103.
I've tried using apply with lambdas, but I can't get the logic right.
One issue is not being able to use the ID column as dictionary keys for the 'Suggested_Movements' column because they are hashable. To get around that, I tried converting them first to strings and then back to integers so they would be recognized as dictionary keys as follows:

```
df['to add'] = df['Suggested_Movements'].apply(lambda x: x.get(int(df['StationID'].to_string())))
```

This gave me the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0      102\n1      103\n2       11\n3       12\n4      133\n5      134\n6      145\n7      156\n8      157\n9      161\n10     172\n11       2\n12     217\n13      24\n14     259\n15     270\n16
```

which shows that there are additional characters added to the station indices. I suppose I could add `.split('\\')[0]` to get only the number I need, but something is going wrong with that too, and this seems to convoluted to be the proper way to do this.
I also tried this:
 `df['To_Add'] = df[StationID].map(df["Suggested_Movements"]).fillna(df['To_add'])`

based on another question, which just gave me a copy of the whole dictionary in the last column.

Comment: Why station 103 gets 6 added? station 102 sends 5 bikes, but station 11 only sends bikes to station 17 and station 11 (does it makes sense that a station sends bikes to itself?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"StationID": [102, 103, 11],
                   "Bikes_available": [10,3, 2],
                   "Suggested_movement": [{11: 3, 103: 5}, {103: 3, 15: 3}, {17: 1, 11: 1}]})
# create a dataframe from the list of dictionaries and sum the values
to_add = pd.DataFrame(list(df["Suggested_movement"])).sum()
```

Then `concat` `df` and `to_add` by index `StationID`, drop the values that were not in `df` in the first place and fill `to_add` NaN with 0:

```
df = (pd.concat([df.set_index("StationID"), to_add], axis=1, join="outer")\
                    .dropna(subset=["Bikes_available", "Suggested_movement"])
                    .fillna(0))
```

As @jcaliz pointed out, the result is, assuming each station can send bike to itself as it seems to be from the expected output (although you should get 8 for 103):

```
   Bikes_available Suggested_movement    0
11               2.0     {17: 1, 11: 1}  4.0
102             10.0    {11: 3, 103: 5}  0.0
103              3.0    {103: 3, 15: 3}  8.0
```

Now, if one station *cannot send bike to itself*, you can remove the corresponding keys from the `Suggested_movement` as so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"StationID": [102, 103, 11],
                   "Bikes_available": [10,3, 2],
                   "Suggested_movement": [{11: 3, 103: 5}, {103: 3, 15: 3}, {17: 1, 11: 1}]})

df["Suggested_movement"] = df.apply(lambda x: {k:v for k,v in 
                           x["Suggested_movement"].items() if k != x["StationID"]},
                                    axis=1)
to_add = pd.DataFrame(list(df["Suggested_movement"])).sum()
df = (pd.concat([df.set_index("StationID"), to_add], axis=1, join="outer")\
                    .dropna(subset=["Bikes_available", "Suggested_movement"])
                    .fillna(0))
```

The result is then :

```
     Bikes_available Suggested_movement    0
11               2.0            {17: 1}  3.0
102             10.0    {11: 3, 103: 5}  0.0
103              3.0            {15: 3}  5.0
```

Hope it helps